# How to install ADAM on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, active-directory

How do I install ADAM/LDS on a machine running Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bit? I have found guides for Vista but they require you to have a second computer running xp to install it first. When I run the [installer](https://web.archive.org/web/20111230231555/http://www.microsoft.com:80/download/en/details.aspx?id=4201), I get an error about not having enough memory but I have around 30GB of free space. See [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20091201113014/http://geekswithblogs.net:80/cicorias/archive/2007/10/10/Installing-ADAM-on-Vista.aspx) for a guide example about installing it on Vista.

Comment: I think it was renamed for 7: [Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) for Windows7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14683)

Comment: @ techie007, post your comment as an answer please.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was renamed for 7.

Check out "[Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS) for Windows7](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14683)" at Microsoft's download site.